# AM PM format angular (typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Cannot add formatting for time.
Should be displayed in 12 hours, AM PM format;
I need this one for a subscription form for customers.
The Date and Time I am using for schedule

How to get 12 hours AM PM time format?

```js
private weekday = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
private monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
];

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {

}

getCurrentUrl() {
  return this.router.url.split('#')[0];
}

formatDate(dt) {
  const _date = new Date(dt);
  const nameDay = this.weekday[_date.getDay()];
  return nameDay + ', ' + _date.getDate() + ' ' + this.monthNames[_date.getMonth()] + ' ' + _date.getFullYear();
}

getTime(dt) {
    const _date = new Date(dt);
    let _hour = _date.getHours().toString();
    let _min = _date.getMinutes().toString();
    _hour = _hour.length === 1 ? '0' + _hour.toString() : _hour;
    _min = _min.length === 1 ? '0' + _min.toString() : _min;
    return _hour + ':' + _min;
```

Comment: Please take a look at the example I provided and let me know if it helps. If it does help please upvote and accept my answer. If you need more help please let me know. I'd be happy to assist in any way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like I need more detail. But given what you have provided:

https://codepen.io/nstanard/pen/bzbdrJ

```
let date = new Date();

function formatDate(dt) {
    // const _date = new Date(dt);
    // const nameDay = this.weekday[dt.getDay()];
    // return nameDay + ', ' + dt.getDate() + ' ' + this.monthNames[dt.getMonth()] + ' ' + dt.getFullYear();
  let normalizeHour = dt.getHours() >= 13 ? dt.getHours() - 12 : dt.getHours()
  return dt.getHours() >= 13 ? normalizeHour + 'PM' : normalizeHour + 'AM'
}

console.log(formatDate(date))
```

Here is the hour of a date object formatted for AM and PM.

### Read more

**However,** if you are using TypeScript and Angular I suggest you take a look a the following example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sc1ihu

1. create a date object
   `dateNow : Date = new Date();`
2. Use the date format in the html.
   `{{dateNow | date:'short'}}`

Using DatePipe is part of ng.common and IS best practice.

Comment: That is not the best use of Angular, or for that matter JavaScript.  Both provide built in methods for formatting dates and times.  A simple online search for date time string formatting in javascript will turn up many options.

Comment: You're not wrong. And given your question on why you got downvoted i'm not surprised to see you make a comment. But I'm trying to answer their question from the perspective of the code they have provided. Not just from the resources they listed in the name. I personally use MomentJS for date and time displays. But that wasn't referenced in the question. I do not know what restrictions they have.

Comment: Yes it's lacking in details.  But Angular implies HTML generation, so I felt pretty comfortable suggesting the pipe system.  Yes, the OP doesn't say whether this is for markup, or back end.  If it's for markup (HTML), you definitely want to do this in the HTML with a pipe.  If it's for internal use  (code to code), then there needs to be more clarification in the question about exactly why the formatting is needed.

Comment: I would like to change my code instead of using anything additional

Comment: @СлаваМельников - Please take a look at the example I provided. And if it helped you please accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me that the actual answer to OP is the stackblitz cde. Please provide the relevant part of the code in the answer itself. Link-only answers are considered "not an answer".

Comment: many thanks, @nstanard ! you are really helping. I'm using angular7, what should I provide?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going to the hassle of creating your own date formatter, why don't you use the built-in datePipe?

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){
    this.datePipe.transform(this._date, 'yyyy MM dd');
}
```

you can use all the built-in values of the DatePipe.
Don't forget to add DatePipe to your providers array.